# Will Starship get refueled in Mars orbit?

Tags: spacex, mars, spacex-starship, refueling

The current plans of Spacex is to have Starship get refueled in LEO and then fly to Mars and refuel it there on the ground. Will Starship also have to get refuel while it is in orbit around Mars on it's return trip?

Comment: @Jasen Nice pun, but: So far all the hype was substantially justified, against all odds, except for the timeline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mars has lower gravity and a smaller radius which significantly reduces the delta-v to reach orbit. Given that, and possibly also a lighter cargo load, Earth return can be done with only surface refueling.

Comment: As Elon Musk puts it, Earth is kind of a worst-case scenario for getting to orbit: high gravity and thick atmosphere. Most other bodies in the solar system are much, much easier. Mars' gravity is about one third of Earth's and its atmosphere only one hundredth. You can easily SSTO from Mars with lots of delta-v to spare to get to Earth.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I suppose musk has never heard of Venus then

Comment: @Topcode Or Jupiter. Or of the 1000 km/h storms on Saturn. "The weather forecast indicates that a launch today is unlikely. Everybody back into the bunkers."

Comment: Or the sun. I thought it was pretty clear he was limiting things to the planets one could conceivably be launching a spacecraft from the surface of. Of those, Venus is the only one that even *has* a surface.

Comment: It's not really about surface gravity or radius. Low surface gravity reduces the thrust required to lift off and the gravity losses in ascent, but even on Earth gravity losses are a small fraction of the overall delta-v requirements. What you really want to look at is escape velocity, which for Mars is 5 km/s, compared to 11 km/s for Earth.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff true, what I wrote is for low mars orbit, a spacecraft would still need to climb the gravity well to escape velocity. Will try to amend when not on my phone

Comment: A minimal circular orbit has a velocity about 70% of surface escape velocity, so the relative proportions are the same. Where LEO velocity is around 7.8 km/s, an equivalent Mars orbit is about 3.5 km/s.